# Python dataframe to dictionary (keys: position of the column, value the names of the variables of the dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary whose keys contain the position of the column and the value the names of the variables of the dataframe.

DataFrame:

```
    ID   A   B   C
0   p    1   3   2
1   q    4   3   2
2   r    4   0   9
```

Output should be like this:

```
Dictionary = {'1': [ID], '2': [A], '3': [B],'4': [C]}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'ID' instead of [ID]?

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` with dict comprehension - create strings keys and one element lists:

```
d = {str(k): [v] for k, v in enumerate(df.columns, 1)}
print (d)
{'1': ['ID'], '2': ['A'], '3': ['B'], '4': ['C']}
```

Or if need intgers without lists use:

```
d1 = dict(enumerate(df.columns, 1))
print (d1)
{1: 'ID', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'C'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.to_series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) + [`Series.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) to iterate on `index, value` information.

```
# You should set the index of the new serie using the index optional parameter, 
# this will be an iterable from 1 to len(columns) + 1
serie = df.columns.to_series(index=range(1, len(df.columns)+1))
d = {index: [value] for index, value in serie.items()}
```

Or, if you prefer one-line solution:

```
d = {index: [value] for index, value in df.columns.to_series(index=range(1, len(df.columns)+1)).items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: ['ID'], 2: ['A'], 3: ['B'], 4: ['C']}
```